# Start dialog activity but invisible?

Tags: android

I find a problem that when i add a floatwindow in onCreate then can not start an dialog normally!

```
public void createFloatButton(int status) {

    int screenWidth = mWindowAdmin.getDisplayWidth();
    int screenHeight = mWindowAdmin.getDisplayHeight();
    if (mFloatButton == null) {
        mFloatButton = new FloatButton(mContext);
        if (mLayoutParams == null) {
            mLayoutParams = new LayoutParams();
            mLayoutParams.type = LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
            mLayoutParams.format = PixelFormat.RGBA_8888;
            mLayoutParams.flags = LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
            mLayoutParams.gravity = GravityCompat.START | Gravity.TOP;
            mLayoutParams.width = mFloatButton.getViewWidth();
            mLayoutParams.height = mFloatButton.getViewHeight();
            mLayoutParams.x = screenWidth;
            mLayoutParams.y = screenHeight / 2;
        }
        mFloatButton.setLayoutParams(mLayoutParams);
        mWindowManager.addView(mFloatButton, mLayoutParams);  //problem line

        if (status == -1) {
            if (!SwitchUtils.isMobileDataEnabled(mContext) && !WifiAdmin.getInstance(mContext).isWifiEnabled()) {
                mFloatButton.setStatus(FloatButton.STATUS_NONE);
            } else {
                mFloatButton.setStatus(FloatButton.STATUS_NORMAL);
            }
        } else {
            mFloatButton.setStatus(status);
        }
    }
}
```

in An Activity onCreate() invoke the up code then click a button to show a dialog, that dialog will invisible!

Comment: post the relevant code.

Comment: CODEEEE??LOGCATT???XML????

Comment: I guess you are doing something wrong!

Comment: We find it damn near impossible to debug invisible code.

Comment: It is not at all clear what the problem you are having is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the layout params to:

```
 if (mLayoutParams == null) {
                mLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        screenWidth,
                        screenHeight / 2,
                        LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
          LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
          PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
                mLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | GravityCompat.START;
            }
            mFloatButton.setLayoutParams(mLayoutParams);
            mWindowManager.addView(mFloatButton, mLayoutParams);
```

Notice that I used wrap-content for width and height because I do not have FloatButton class. Also, if I use mFloatButton.getWidth() and mFloatButton.getHeight() for width and height - the button view would not show as the width and height may be zero.

The following is a working code based on your code using Button instead of FloatButton class - without status:

```
public void createFloatButton() {
    WindowManager.LayoutParams mLayoutParams = null;
    Button mFloatButton = null;

     DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
     WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
     mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int screenWidth = dm.widthPixels;  
    int screenHeight =  dm.heightPixels;
    if (mFloatButton == null) {
        mFloatButton = new Button(this);
        mFloatButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        // Note: I added background to be able to view button

        if (mLayoutParams == null) {
            mLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    screenWidth,
                    screenHeight / 2,
                    LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
      LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
      PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
            mLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | GravityCompat.START;
        }
        mFloatButton.setLayoutParams(mLayoutParams);
        mWindowManager.addView(mFloatButton, mLayoutParams);  // no problem


    }
}
```

Make sure you add

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

to AndroidManifest

Comment: I'm sorry i can show my add view, i mean invoke the up code in activity on create then can not show the Alertdialog normally first time!

Comment: @Jerry - you need to post the alertdialog code - and where you call it

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); builder.setMessage("Hello");   builder.create().show(); it's the normal code ...it really show()...but can not see it! i set a click in dialog, it works ok!

Comment: @Jason - so you click on floatbutton to launch alertdialog and dialog is there but background is transparent. Is this right?

Comment: oh, It's not! at a activity oncreate i run the up code. at the activity also hava a button, i click to run an AlertDialog! first time is transparent!

Comment: Thank You Very Much! i resolve it but do not know why? i change the context to context.getApplicationContext() to create WindowManager will resolve it!

Comment: @Jason - Good? what context were you using before?

Comment: Before i use activity!